# Mass convert MP3 with Big5 / GB encoded tags to unicode

Tags: mp3, unicode

Most people in asia still used localized version of windows 
(simplied chinese - GB , traditional chinese - Big5, Japanese - JIS)

As a result, a lot of mp3 files I got from them have the tags encoded in localized encoding (song names, album, etc)

Some software can render them properly (windows media player) if you set your windows localization setting to match theirs but most software won't one way or another (winamp, google play)

How can I mass convert tags in localized encoding to unicode? Is there a tool that can do this and, if not, are there scripting APIs that I can use to write my own script to do this (python, perl, php, etc)?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Super User! In Super User, and all the StackExchange sites, shopping or product recommendations are considered off topic and open ended, and sometimes even too localized. Try to reword your question in a way that you are not asking for products, but more of processes; this will help keep it on topic

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: @terdon: I'm guessing Windows going by his post.

Comment: @Karan, I guessed as much but I always ask because you can never be sure and because the OP asked for scripting solutions which are, often, much easier on other platforms. I thought she may have access to different OSs.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org) player with the [foo_chacon](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Components_0.9/Chacon_%28foo_chacon%29) component:

[image: 1]

You can also use [ID3iconv](http://www.zhoufeng.net/eng/id3iconv/) with one of the frontends mentioned [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-auto-convert-mp3-id3-tag-charset-to-unicode-utf-8/).